# cron job problem with soapclient included in php

Tags: php, soap, cron

I have a php script, and need to run it everyday.  This script has a soapclient, and it works fine if I run it as a script using browser directly.  However, some fatal errors if I set it as a cron job.

The script is very simple as "crontest.php"

```
<?php 

$mage_url = 'http://******.com/api/?wsdl'; 
$mage_user = '*****'; 
$mage_api_key = '******';

$soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url ); 
echo "success";

exit;
?>
```

And the cronjob I set is

```
0 8 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/duan/public_html/scripts/crontest.php
```

The error it gives is

**Fatal error**:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in **/home/duan/public_html/scripts/crontest.php**

It works fine if I remove line

```
$soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url );
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Maybe when you run this in your browser it's php-cgi that handle the script and that here it's php-cli, try to see if your problem does not come from that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running your script by calling php directly, try using lynx to get the server to load the page through an http request:

`/usr/bin/lynx -source http://example.com/cron.php`

This should cause the script to be run in the same manner as when you view it yourself through your web browser.  Test it out on the command line first, and then for your cron job you can just divert the output to /dev/null or a log as appropriate:

`/usr/bin/lynx -source http://example.com/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include the file nusoap.php or load the php library. It is only included after version 5.0.1, but the server might not use it (especially if you use nusoap, which has the same class name).

You should search the website code and look for the inclusion of *nusoap.php* or a command like *dl('SoapClient')* (dl loads a php library).

If its not nusoap, you could try the command **php -m** and see if SoapClient is there. If not try **php -v**.